# Is there a way to add a dynamic URL token to images so that the move from local host to live doesn't require code change?

Tags: media

Is there a way to add a dynamic URL token to images so that the move from local host to live doesn't require code change?

When uploading images in content, the path changes form localhost to live, how can I have it consistent so the database can be exported without changes?

[image]

I would like to leave out the name of the site in the path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handling of the links in the field having a WYSIWYG editor, or any other long text field is a common issue when the site moves from one server (say dev) to other (say stage or production).
The links should be saved in such a way that they do not break.

**[Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic)** module does that for you.

> Pathologic is an [input filter](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/filter) which can correct paths in links and images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or the content was moved to a different server. Pathologic can also solve the problem of missing images and broken links in your site’s RSS feeds. [See more example use cases](http://drupal.org/node/257026#example-use-cases) on the documentation page.

Comment: True, I totally forgot thos module, the backend life :D.  If I remember it had some limitations, but it's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no such token. Even if it exists it will be hard to use: think in all places that the token should be used and token must be processed: inside content texts, link fields, even variables.

You should to use the same path for all enviroments.

If you really need different paths (for example, to hide a name) I suggest you to use a symlink in one of the environments: For example, if your local path is `/NAME/path` and live path is `/NAME-TO-HIDE/path` you can create a symlink that points from `/NAME/` to `/NAME-TO-HIDE/` in the live site. Nobody will see the NAME-TO-HIDE string but webserver will reach the right files thanks to the symlink.

Comment: Ok, I will just name the site the same thing, what I have been doing in the past is naming sites like localhost/site1  localhost/testing  localhost/sandbox ect...I guess not good practice

Comment: Aquia Dev Desktop appends DD to every new site URL on local host ..I can't use the same path for all environments...or is there an Aquia setting?

Comment: I don't use Acquia Dev Desktop, but I'm not sure if I understand your problem. I don't know what you mean when you say 'appends DD to new site URL on localhost'.. and is strange that Acquia don't allow you to use the same internal path . You should edit your question given your setup with all details.

Comment: I'll email Acquia, I mean this with Acquai: when you create a new site, instead of having a URL path like localhost/example (XAMPP), it give you something like example:dd:8083, it puts :DD suffix on all new sites

Comment: It's seems that they change the domain, no the path part of the URL (the path inside the server).

Comment: When you upload images, the DD is appended. Adding images on live site URL is:  /testing/sites/default/files/content_images/left.png    adding the same image on Localhost URL is:  /sites/xuzo.dd/files/content_images/left.png , now I don't know why folder structure is not the same on live and local host...it's the same on both in FTP, sites/default/files/content_images